# DoDragDrop() - droptarget is another application (word or excel)

Tags: wpf, drag-and-drop, ms-word, cursor

In my WPF application I have implimented drag drop and am placing my PNG image in a DataObject then passing that to the DoDragDrop method.  It seems rather hit-and-miss as to which applications I can drop on.  Excell yes, Word no.

I'm here looking to see if there is a way to check if the target application (MS Word) will accept the object being dragged to it.  Currently the image looks like it is being dragged but Word does nothing with it.  When dragging from Excel to Word I get a red icon indicating the drag won't work, I need to present that same icon if my drag won't work (if possible).

All the articles I've seem to indicate that the DropTarget impliments the DragOver and Feedback events, not my app as the DragSource?  Is this correct or could I use those events to check the DropTarget?

It's odd that Word won't accept my image but Excel will.  Is there some other way to drag drop that would be more robust?

Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: I changed the code that creates the DataObject and instead of putting BitMap and the bitmap image (from the PNG) I add a list of filenamess that contain the PNG.  This code:  dataObj = new DataObject(DataFormats.FileDrop, (files.Cast<string>()).ToArray<string>()); Now the drag drop works for Word but not Excel.

Answer (score 3):

Drag+Drop in Excel looks remarkably broken, at least in my edition (2013).  It will not accept a file dragged from Explorer for example and otherwise produces a great many painting artifacts and drops in the wrong location.  But what does work is dragging a bitmap object.

To make it work both with Excel and Word, you'll want to specify *more* than one format.  This bit of Winforms test code operated well, using a sample image named "transparent.png" in the Pictures folder.  Tweak as necessary to drag your own image file in WPF:

```
    private void Form1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
        string path = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyPictures);
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, "transparent.png");
        using (var bmp = new Bitmap(path)) {
            var data = new DataObject();
            var files = new System.Collections.Specialized.StringCollection();
            files.Add(path);
            data.SetFileDropList(files);   // This format works in Word
            data.SetImage(bmp);            // This format works in Excel
            DoDragDrop(data, DragDropEffects.Copy);
        }
    }
```